# Infinite uniform distribution

Tags: electrostatics

I have been looking at how to calculate the initial  electrostatic field of a universe filled with a homogenous uniform charge density.

This question seems deceptively easy.

Intuitively, you would assume that because there is equal charge on either side of any point in space, then the electric field is zero everywhere.

However:

$\nabla \cdot \vec{E} = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}$

$\nabla \cdot 0 = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_{0}}$

$\rho = 0$ and hence there cannot be a charge density. A contradiction! Apparently the E field is not translational invariant, which to me seems ridiculous.

To calculate the E field, I wanted to start from the potential

$V = \iiint \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{\rho}{|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'|} d^3 r'$

I used spherical coordinates,  and considered an infinite extension. From here I obtained  an identicle potential to the potential inside a  sphere

$V= \frac{q}{8\pi\epsilon_{0}R} (3-\frac{r^2}{R^2}) $ where $R = \infty$

Translating in terms of charge density

$V(r) = \frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}(\frac{R^2}{2}-\frac{r^2}{6})$

Now, you may think that were done, however doing the same operation but for a different origin of coordinates  yields the same potential function, defined in terms of a new radial distance from that origin. Clearly the potential is not unique and yields different electric fields

I believe this is  because the above formula only yields valid results given V=0 at infinity. Which is not the case given the above analysis.

So my question is, for infinite extension. What boundary conditions would be appropriate for this scenario(+ the modified formula)

and what would be the solution for this scenario actually be?

Comment: Why is $E= 0$ when you have "a homogenous uniform charge density"? Gauss' law tells us to consider the charge *inside* a closed Gauss surface when calculating $E$.

Comment: As  stated, the diferential form of gauss law proves $E≠0$ given $\rho ≠ 0$. I'm not claiming $E=0$ for a fact, gauss law disproves that instantly. Howver I would not recommend using the integral form of gauss law for solving for E, since this method requires the field to be rotationaly invariant for you to say E and DA are parrallel. Pick 2 sphres of diferent centers, E is aparently "rotationaly invariant" about both  and thus E and da are parrallel for both spheres you arbitrarily pick. Leading to the multiple fields you could calculate for this situation, much like the potentials I describe

Comment: Also for anyone: I am aware maxwells equations are non unique without boundary conditions. However I am looking for the most sensible boundary condition for a solution that has a homogenous solution set to 0, and for those boundary conditions, the solution is unique ( unlike the failed attempt in my question)

Answer (score 0):

This has no single solution, a mathematician may perhaps say it is ill-posed. There is no single best boundary condition or a solution here; a specific choice of boundary condition may produce one solution (if the condition holds for a surface entirely at a finite distance from the origin of the coordinate system), or many solutions (if the condition holds only in infinity).

For example, if we say $V=0$ at a sphere of radius $R$ centered at the origin of the coordinate system, then the Poisson equation has single definite solution. But the position of the center and the radius is arbitrary.

If the boundary condition is merely that at infinity $V\to\infty$, this does not even fix single solution, because it admits infinity of above described solutions.

Comment: Can you briefly explain why setting a  boundary condition at infinity yields multiple solutions, I thought that it should fix a single solution? Or is this only because I have  chosen an infinite distribution? Also, even if V=0 at a finite sphere,  this solution depends on the coordinate you chose, and thus different coordinates yield different solutions even with a boundary condition not an infinity? Or am I misunderstanding what you mean. I need to go over the uniqueness theorem for poissons equation more rigourously with infinite distributions in mind!

Comment: The uniqueness theorem is based on the assumption that $V=0$ or $\nabla V = 0$  on some fixed boundary or in infinity. It can be extended to more complicated conditions, such as $V=const.$ or to some limited set of prescribed functions $V=f(\mathbf r)$ on the boundary, but it doesn't work with "boundary condition" of type $V\to\infty$ in infinity. You mentioned examples of this, your $V$ quadratic in $r$ can be centered anywhere and still obey all conditions. Wikipedia has nice proof of the uniqueness theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_theorem_for_Poisson%27s_equation